# RabbitMQ connections is growing abnormally

Tags: c#, .net, kubernetes, rabbitmq, microservices

I am using RabbitMQ to store my micro services log. I have a send message method that its code is the below:

```
    ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ConnectionFactory
    {
        HostName = host,
        UserName = username,
        Password = password,
        VirtualHost= vhost
    };
    using (IConnection connection = connectionFactory.CreateConnection())
    {
        using (IModel model = connection.CreateModel())
        {
            string text = microService + "-" + messagetype;
            var arguments = new Dictionary<string, object> { { "x-queue-type", "quorum" } };
            model.QueueDeclare(text, durable: true, exclusive: false, autoDelete: false, arguments);
            byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);
            model.BasicPublish(string.Empty, text, null, bytes);
        }
    }
```

It works fine and it does not open so many connections. But then I have a worker service that check all of my queues and set a consumer for them if no consumers exist on it. My worker service code is the below:

```
            ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ConnectionFactory
            {
                HostName = queue.HostName,
                UserName = queue.Username,
                Password = queue.Password,
                VirtualHost = queue.VirtualHostName
            };
            var connection = connectionFactory.CreateConnection();
            var channel = connection.CreateModel();
            if (channel.ConsumerCount(queueName) == 0)
            {
                var arguments = new Dictionary<string, object> { { "x-queue-type", "quorum" } };
                channel.QueueDeclare(queueName, durable: true, exclusive: false, autoDelete: false, arguments);

                var consumer = new EventingBasicConsumer(channel);
                consumer.Received += (model, ea) =>
                {
                    try
                    {
                        var body = ea.Body.ToArray();
                        var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(body);
                        SaveMessage(message);
                        channel.BasicAck(ea.DeliveryTag, false);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        channel.BasicNack(ea.DeliveryTag, false, true);
                    }
                };
                var consumerTag = channel.BasicConsume(queue: queueName,
                 autoAck: false,
                 consumer: consumer);
            }
            else
            {
                channel.Close();
                connection.Close();
            }
```

The above code execute every 5 minutes and after a while it opens so many connections on RabbitMQ. If I close connection after setting consumer, it won't be created.

What is the best solution to close connections or to set consumers on queues except worker service?

And one thing else, my RabbitMQ is on Kubernetes.